# UITextView +2 in viewcontroller. textViewDidEndEditing called twice, how to manage it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I'm have some Core data code that needs to run IF textView1 textViewDidEndEditing. and then stop and not run the code from textView2 swell
as of now i just runs all the code in the textViewDidEndEditing. even tho i have a if statement. but i do it wrong. Because it runs the code from both IF statements...

How do it make it run only if textView1 is done editing ?
And again run the code for textView2 when that's done editing

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

if ((textView = textView1)){
 NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
    TextView *aTextView = [TextView MR_createEntity];
    aTextView.belongsTo = @"jegKomTil1";
    // Build the predicate to find the person sought
    NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"jegKomTil1"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"belongsTo == %@", predicateString];
    TextView *aTextView1 = [TextView MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate inContext:localContext];
    // If a person was founded
    if (aTextView1) { // Update its age
        aTextView1.textDataView = textView1.text;
       }
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
}
if ((textView = textView2)){
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
    TextView *aTextView = [TextView MR_createEntity];
    aTextView.belongsTo = @"jegKomTil2";
    // Build the predicate to find the person sought
    NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"jegKomTil2"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"belongsTo == %@", predicateString];
    TextView *aTextView1 = [TextView MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate inContext:localContext];
    // If a person was founded
    if (aTextView1) { // Update its age
        aTextView1.textDataView = textView2.text;
    }
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    NSLog(@"textViewDidEndEditing: 2");
}
```

Comment: if (textview == textView1). (See the difference?)

Comment: @nickfalk yea i noticed the difference. but will it work or should i do what igrekde set as answer ?

Comment: It should work just fine. I don't know what you're planning to have the app do eventually, but checking against an object instance is probably fine. I'd rather have you give them more explicit names, than using tags, as tags don't really read that well...

Comment: try if , else if instead of if, if in the above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the if statements were the culprits. Also there was a huge amount of code duplication there. I've made quick attempt to simplify your logic as it seems the only really difference between the two are the strings you're using for the belongsTo property and the NSPredicate instance...

```
BOOL textViewMatchFound = (textView == textView1 || textView == textView2);

// The BOOL / outer if won't be necessary if you textView1 and textView2 are the ONLY textViews triggering this method... 
if (textViewMatchFound) {
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
    TextView *aTextView = [TextView MR_createEntity];

    NSString *arrivalText = @"jegKomTil1";
    if (textView == textView2) {
        arrivalText = @"jegKomTil2";
    }

    aTextView.belongsTo = arrivalText;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"belongsTo == %@", arrivalText];
    TextView *anotherTextView = [TextView MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate inContext:localContext];

    // If a person was found
    if (anotherTextView) { // Update its age
        anotherTextView.textDataView = textView.text;
    }
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
}
```

Comment: that works fine. if i only wanted textView1.text what about textView2.text ? as it's 2 UITextViews i'm dealing with

Comment: had a flaw in my code. in textView2 code it should be textView2.text. but never the less how would this simplified code work with that ? i appreciate what your doing. i edited my post to reflect my code

Comment: You don't need to refer to textView1 and textView2. The method-parameter textView is pointing to the exact same memory location. There are, as far as I can see, nowhere you're actually changing any object or variable that are outside the scope of the method.

Comment: OK, I've update my code based on your information. You can simply hook up to the method's textView-parameter as it is referring to whichever textView sent you there...

Comment: A bit uncertain about what you're asking. The `textViewDidEndEditing` is a delegate method. Normally the viewController would be the delegate for both textViews.

Comment: doesn't work. it only saves textview2 and not textview1 . at least theres no data for textview1. in textview1 window i can only see the data  "<null>"

Comment: for some reason it aint saving the content of textView1, textView2 works flawless

Comment: Very odd, could it be that you haven't hooked up the CoreData properly? The textViews are treated 100% identical. It's a bit hard to comment further as it suggest the problem might lie elsewhere...

Comment: Ikke noe problem! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the property *tag* when creating your textviews:

```
UITextView *textView1 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
textView1.tag = 1;
UITextView *textView2 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20)];
textView1.tag = 2;
```

And then use:

```
if (textView.tag == 1)
...
```

Comment: Not a huge fan of the above solution as 1, 2 etc. don't really read that well. I'd much rather have less generic names for the textViews.

Comment: @KennyVB, yes, you can find it in Attributes Inspector -> View -> Tag

Comment: @nickfalk, if he has only two TextViews, there won't be a big problem with readability.

Comment: @igrekde fair enough, but he'll have to do a bit of extra plumbing to get there so I'm not sure what the upside would be?